# RESTful interface when you can only have a single instance of an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am adding an item to an inventory for a company from a master list in a Rails app.  Normally, posting multiple times with the same item should create more of the items. Obviously, I could limit it to a single instance.

I'm thinking of doing it as just a single action of toggling into inventory. You'd always post and if it exists, you delete the item out of the user's inventory and if it doesn't exist, you add it.

Does handling it this way seem reasonable? Or is there a better way (obviously doing posts / deletes) or other?

Comment: Can you show your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

This could be best defined with a path something like, (or something similar that suits your application structure):

```
PUT /users/:used_id/items/:item_id/inventory
DELETE /users/:used_id/items/:item_id/inventory
```

Neither route should accept any additional parameters. The `PUT` would add the item to the users inventory if it doesn't already exist, and perhaps return an error if it does. Conversely, the `DELETE` should remove the item from the users inventory if it exists, and perhaps return an error if it doesn't.